# How to save data in userdefaults when is from a model

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I have a Model like this

```
struct House: Codable {
    let address: String?
    let rooms: String?
    let garage: Garage
}

struct Garage: Codable {
    let space: String?
    let numbers_of_ cars: String?
}
```

I get from a api the data and set to can show it, 
now I need to save in userdefaults to can show info if there is not any network o wifi

I am trying like this

```
var itemItems = [House]()

fileprivate func fetchData() {
        Service.shared.fetchCourses { (houses, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to fetch houses:", err)
                return
            }

        self.itemItems = houses!

        var itemsToSave = [House]()
        for i in 0..<self.itemItems.count {
            itemsToSave.append(self.itemItems[i])
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayToSave, forKey : "arrayToSave")

        }
    }
```

but!! I get an error
check the image

https://i.ibb.co/bHhtj28/Captura-de-Pantalla-2019-11-24-a-la-s-4-25-18-p-m.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save custom structs to `UserDefaults` directly.

But as both structs conform to `Codable` encode them

```
var itemItems = [House]()

fileprivate func fetchData() {
    Service.shared.fetchCourses { (houses, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to fetch houses:", err)
            return
        }

        self.itemItems = houses!
        do {
           let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.itemItems)
           UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey : "houses")
        } catch { print(error) }      
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! now i dont have the error, but, look that when i try to get the data not working
let getDataHouses = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "houses") ?? ""

is right? because when i print it , is ""

Comment: Of course you have to load and decode the `Data` with `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: i am doing like this, but i get error, please help :)

let dataHousesStore = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "houses")!
        
        do {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataFinal = try jsonDecoder.decode(House.self, from: dataHousesStore)

        }
        catch { print("error" , error) }

Comment: Please **read** the error message. You have to decode `[House].self`, an array.